# Не отправляется письмо о заказе клиенту Opencart

Tags: php, cms, opencart

В общем, недавно перестали отправляться письма на почту к клиенту об оформлении заказа. Письмо на почту администратора о том же заказе приходит. Спам проверял, ничего не закомментировано, код с отправкой письма не менял. До этого ставил модуль "Шаблоны писем", после них вообще перестала отправляться какая-либо почта, снес его под чистую, начали отправляться только на мыло админа. Почта доменная, отправка идет с нее, раньше все работало. В чем может быть проблема? Просто письма с этой почты отправляются.

Comment: у клиента в спаме смотрели?

Comment: так точно. Раньше оно приходила в спам, и это уже другая проблема. Сейчас оно не приходит вовсе.

Comment: майл сервер яндекс гугл, или майл поставили фильтр и выкосили вас, меняй исходящие адреса

Comment: не нахожусь ни в одном чс по тестам почты. Еще раз, просто почта спокойно отправляется